# Windows Server DNS resetting SOA field

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, windows-sbs-2003

I'm attempting to setup split horizon dns for a small business (Windows 2003 SBS). The network internally uses a .local domain. Now I've setup a zone for the extern domain, but am having troubles getting the results I (think) I want.

The problem is that the SOA field for the new zone keeps resetting to the internalserver.domain.local, even though I want it to be srv1.domain.com. internalserver.domain.local is the name of the DC/DNS server. This leads to trouble when I run a diagnostic software from outside the network, since it cannot resolve the .local adress.

Also, if I do `dig @ns.domain.com host.domain.local` I can get the information from the internal network, which I clearly do not want. How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your life would be easier if you had your ISP or another hosted DNS provider host the public version of the zone.

Comment: We've been having dyndns doing dns for us the last five years (set up before I started at the company). However, times are as they are, and if we could do dns ourselves we'd save money.

Comment: I hear ya - but you can get premium DNS hosting for less then $5 a month through someone like loaddns.com. Also, most registrars include DNS hosting with your registration - have you explored that route?

Comment: The registrar doesn't provide that service, however I can change registrar without cost... I'll look into wether this would be cheaper than the current option!

Comment: That's the route we went down in the end.